# Horror film in space, man falls into space and shatters

Tags: identify-this-movie

Sat with a few mates and we all recollect this one scene from a movie, but none of us can recall the film at all, even if its a horror film or not, but based on the violent death its a good guess.

Basically there's a crew of people aboard a spaceship, and they board a dormant spaceship, the boarding mechanism/bridge between the 2 ships gets severed and there aren't enough spaceships to make the trip back for the whole of the boarding party. One of the people who doesn't get a suit tries to get wrapped up in the interior of the ship they are currently in as a makeshift suit. They line up both ships airlocks, and try to use the force of opening the airlock of the ship they are in to catapult all of them into main ship, it doesn't work and of the guys flies off into space, freezes, and shatters into pieces

One of the only horror space movies I can think of is Event Horizon, but it's been a long time since I've watched that, I'll be more annoyed if it is and I've forgotten

Comment: It sounds like the new Star Trek. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p349Kb1SFlo

Comment: There are some scenes in ***Event Horizon*** which are similar to what you are describing, but I am pretty sure it's not the movie you are looking for either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the movie [Sunshine](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0448134/):

In that particular scene, they meet up with the sister ship that was thought lost. They board it to find it empty and before they know it, they must evacuate back.

Comment: Such a great movie! How could I forget that scene...

Comment: Thats the one! I knew Sunshine was another horror space film but I thought it was an older film than that. I've managed to find a small clip of the trailer which shows the bit I'm after, me and my mates tip our hats off to you

Comment: It was an okay movie (IMHO), but had a huge plot flaw (all the radioactive material on earth to kick start the sun? Not even close to enough to even make a flicker).

Comment: @AndrewMorris thanks! One of my favorite movies, especially gorgeous on Blu-Ray.